# How was Maxwell able to derive velocity distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

Did he assume that their velocities follow some kind of statistical distribution and fit the parameters accordingly. Or did he mathematically prove it?

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Read this article on the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.](http://www.eoht.info/m/page/Maxwell-Boltzmann+distribution).  The full Clausius paper can be found [here](http://www.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Clausius%20%281857%29_Nature%20motion%20we%20call%20heat.pdf).

Comment: Would this be better at [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @BySymmetry and Aaron the question is not about how Maxwell got the idea of the story behind it. But the derivation itself. Now no one would expect a derivation in History of Science and Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original argument goes a bit like this. Suppose the velocity $\mathbf v=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ follows some sort of distribution $f(\mathbf v)$. We can make the following arguments.

1. Since the gas particles can move in any direction, and any two directions are equivalent to one another, $f$ can only depend on the magnitude of $\mathbf v$, $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$.
2. As there are particles everywhere, they collide a lot and mix the components of the velocities with each other. We then say that the three components of motion should be statistically independent, $f(\mathbf v)=f_x(v_x)f_y(v_y)f_z(v_z)$, and also expect that the velocities of any two particles are uncorrelated as well.

Combining these two assumptions and doing many calculations we conclude that the only nice enough (differentiable, normalizable) form for $f$ is

$$f(\mathbf v)=Ce^{-\alpha v^2}$$

for $\alpha>0$. Imposing normalization and that total kinetic energy for $N\gg1$ particles should be $\frac{3}{2}Nk_BT$ allows us to write

$$\alpha=\frac{m}{2k_BT}$$

Which properly gives us the Maxwell velocity distribution.

Comment: Could you throw some light on why combining these two assumptions and doing many calculations we conclude that the only nice enough (smooth, normalizable) form for $f$ is $Ce^{-\alpha v^2}$?

Comment: @user1936752 first we use fact 1 applied on 2 to find out that $f_x=f_y=f_z$ and that they are all even functions. We then take the logarithm of the decomposition into three functions, remembering again to write $f(\mathbf v)=f(v)$ and differentiate w.r.t. one component of the velocity and noting that all the other derivatives should have the same form. Solving the resulting equations fixes the form of $f$. Normalizability fixes that $\alpha>0$.